# OpenCV StereoSGBM mat output array bad access in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv

Trying to create a disparity map in xcode but keep getting exc bad access when running stereosgbm.compute and can't figure out why. The output array for the function is a mat but I can't figure out how to initialize it to get it to work.

here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DisparityGenerator.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"




@implementation DisparityGenerator

AppDelegate *appDelDG;
cv::Mat matImageR;
cv::Mat matImageL;


+ (UIImage*) dispGen:(int)image{

    appDelDG = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIImage* result = nil;
    //  convert the photo the camera took to MAT

    if(image == 0){

        UIImage *R = [UIImage imageNamed:@"im6"];
        UIImageToMat(R, matImageR);

        UIImage *L = [UIImage imageNamed:@"im2"];
        UIImageToMat(L, matImageL);

    }else{

        UIImage *R = [UIImage imageNamed:@"im6a"];
        UIImageToMat(R, matImageR);

        UIImage *L = [UIImage imageNamed:@"im2a"];
        UIImageToMat(L, matImageL);

    }

    cv::Mat dispArray;;

//    dispArray.create(<#int _rows#>, <#int _cols#>, int _type)

    cv::cvtColor(matImageL,  matImageL,  cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(matImageR, matImageR, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::StereoSGBM  *imbm = cv::StereoSGBM::create(6, 6, 6);
        //cv::StereoBM::create(16, 2);

    imbm->compute(matImageL,matImageR,dispArray);

    result = MatToUIImage(dispArray);

    return result;


}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! i initialized StereoBM wrong. the right way is:

```
    cv::Ptr <cv::StereoBM> imbm = cv::StereoBM::create(0);
```